# DialogFragment with Roboelctric

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, robolectric

I wanted to test if a dialog Fragment is shown or not, with **Roboelectric**.

```
public class SomeDialogActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        DialogFragment someDialogFragment = new SomeDialogFragment();
        someDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "some_dialog");
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to test if this dialog is shown, something like this:

```
@Test
public void dialogFragmentIsShownToTheUser() {
        DialogFragment dialog = new SomeDialogFragment();
        DialogFragment someDialogFragment = new SomeDialogFragment();
        startFragment(someDialogFragment);

        SomeDialogActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(SomeDialogActivity.class);

        Dialog dialog = ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog();
        assertNotNull(dialog);
        assertEquals(.... , ....)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Treat it as normal `fragment` situation. So to check that fragment is shown you need to have next code:

```
@Test
public void dialogFragmentIsShownToTheUser() {
    SomeDialogActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(SomeDialogActivity.class);

    DialogFragment dialogFragment = (DialogFragment) activity.getSupporFragmetManager()
                                       .findFragmentByTag("some_dialog");
    assertNotNull(dialogFragment);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, once the dialogfragment is initialized, it never comes back to the assertNotNull check. its stuck and i get this error.

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f030023
 
`...
android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
 at com.xxx.yyy.zzz.fragments.MacDialogFragment.onCreateDialog(MacDialogFragment.java:36) .....`